# How to get field values from unicode[u'a', u'd'] in odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, list, unicode, odoo, odoo-10

I want to get string form unicode. For this my code is here:

```
@api.multi

    def _select_service_product(self):

        r = []

        for order in self.order_line:

            res = order.product_id.type_service

            r.append(res)

            self.services_infor = r

            l = self.services_infor

            print "test,,,", res, self.services_infor, l
```

services_infor = fields.Char(compute='_select_service_product')

**Now terminal showes:**

test,,, d [False, u'a', u'd'] [False, u'a', u'd']

From here i want values a, b

Answer (score 0):

```
x = u"['a', 'b']"
# either you c an explicitly convert the unicode chars
print str(x)
output : "['a', 'b']"
#use eval function to make the unicode list to original
print eval(x)
output: ['a','b']
```